# Resolving UILabel constraints issues

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm a beginner in UIKit, and I'd like to achieve this layout in a `UITableViewCell`.

[image: Layout with two UIStackView]

UIStackView1 is composed of arranged subviews like these:

[image: UIStackView1 layout]

Both Header Label and Value Label are UILabel, connected with bottom-top anchoring.

UIStackView2 is similar, but Value Label is a UITextField

For some reason, this code produces empty cells.

```swift
func singleFieldsRow() -> UIView {
    
    let viewContainer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 0))
    viewContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    let stackView1: UIStackView = UIStackView()
    stackView1.alignment = .leading
    stackView1.axis = .vertical
    stackView1.distribution = .fillProportionally
    
    viewContainer.addSubview(stackView1)
    
    // stackview1 constraints
    stackView1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    stackView1.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewContainer.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView1.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewContainer.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView1.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewContainer.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    
    let stackView1Container: UIView = UIView()
    viewContainer.addSubview(stackView1Container)
    
    stackView1Container.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stackView1Container.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewContainer.topAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView1Container.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewContainer.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView1Container.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewContainer.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView1Container.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView1.topAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView1Container.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewContainer.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    
    // stackview2
    let stackView2: UIStackView = UIStackView()
    stackView2.alignment = .leading
    stackView2.axis = .vertical
    stackView2.distribution = .equalCentering
    
    stackView1Container.addSubview(stackView2)
    
    stackView2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    
    
    stackView2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView1Container.topAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView1Container.topAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView2.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView1Container.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    
    stackView2.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView1Container.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    stackView2.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView1Container.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    
        
    for field in stack1Fields {
        let fieldContainer = UIView()
        let headerLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
        let valueLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
        
        headerLabel.text = field.title
        headerLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        headerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        
        valueLabel.text = field.value
        valueLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        valueLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        
        fieldContainer.addSubview(headerLabel)
        fieldContainer.addSubview(valueLabel)
        
        headerLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fieldContainer.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        headerLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fieldContainer.topAnchor).isActive = true
        headerLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fieldContainer.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        headerLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fieldContainer.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        
        valueLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fieldContainer.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        valueLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fieldContainer.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        valueLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fieldContainer.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        valueLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fieldContainer.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        
        stackView2.addArrangedSubview(fieldContainer)
    }
    
    
    
    for field in stack2Fields {
        
        let fieldContainer = UIView()
        
        let headerLabel: UILabel = UILabel()
        
        headerLabel.text = productField.title
        headerLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        headerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        
        fieldContainer.addSubview(headerLabel)
        
        let valueTextField: UITextField = UITextField()
        valueTextField.text = productField.value
        valueTextField.keyboardType = .default
        valueTextField.placeholder = "Insert value"
        valueTextField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        fieldContainer.addSubview(valueTextField)
        
        headerLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fieldContainer.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        headerLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fieldContainer.topAnchor).isActive = true
        headerLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fieldContainer.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        headerLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fieldContainer.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        headerLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: valueTextField.topAnchor).isActive = true
        
        valueTextField.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fieldContainer.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        valueTextField.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fieldContainer.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        valueTextField.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fieldContainer.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        valueTextField.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fieldContainer.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        editableStackView.addArrangedSubview(fieldContainer)
    }
    
    
    return viewContainer
}
```

You can see there's an extra Container around the UIStackView1 because there's a piece of code that draws an image on the right side of the UIStackView, but for this example it isn't important.

If I put `sizeToFit()` on `UILabels` I can see some content, but UIStackView1 is collapsed, meaning that every UILabel overlaps each other.

[image: UIStackView1 overlapping content]

I also get these messages on console:

> [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
> Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
> Try this:
> (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
> (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
> (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints)
> (
> "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x28157b4d0 h=--& v=--& UILabel:0x10501b790.width == 33.5   (active)>",
> "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x28157b700 h=--& v=--& UILabel:0x10501ca00.width == 66.5   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28154cc80 UILabel:0x10501b790.width == UIView:0x10501b620.width   (active)>",
> "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x28154cdc0 UILabel:0x10501ca00.width == UIView:0x10501b620.width   (active)>"
> )

`UIStackView2` instead shows correctly, with a `UILabel` and `UITextField` placed vertically one after another.
Some `UITextField` however are shown incorrectly, and the Runtime window gives me this warning.

> x-xcode-debug-views://7f82a530ff20?DBGViewDebuggerLaunchSessionParameter=7f82a530ff20: runtime: Layout Issues: Horizontal position is ambiguous for UITextField.

Am I putting too many constraints?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a couple of intruders in my code.

This line:

```
stackView2.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView1Container.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

must be changed to:

```
stackView2.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView1Container.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

and this one

```
stackView1Container.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView1.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

must be removed.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add constraints to all the views which you are adding to the stack view. Stack view will take care of constraints.

Comment: Yes, I'm not putting constraints on the arranged subviews, but on the their subviews (eg. headerLabel and valueLabel inside fieldContainer, which is an arranged subview).